# How to avoid swipe scrolling and double tap zooming on android 2.3.6 stock browser?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-ui, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have this tetris game I programmed with the intention of learning a bit more on javascript: [elcodedocle.github.io/tetrominos](http://elcodedocle.github.io/tetrominos)

I can play it in most tablet/smartphone browsers, but on my Android 2.3.6 stock browser (Samsung Galaxy Ace ST5830) it has two problems:

Zoom events are not exactly canceled by `user-scalable=no` viewport property: double click and two-finger zooming still work. Sometimes.

The canvas freezes, also sometimes (I'm going mad trying to determine the cause: How the heck you debug a web app running on an android browser??). I'm guessing because of a swipe or drag event triggered that shouldn't be, so it's somehow related to the above. Tapping out of the canvas makes it work again.

I'm using Kineticjs to manipulate the canvas and bind the touch events, on top of jquery-ui for the dialogs and jQuery (not jQuery mobile).

Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: I know this is way late, but to debug the android web browser, try firefox and firefox's remote debugging. As for the canvas freezing, you may need to trigger a refresh on it when swiping.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with the device's processing speed.. evrery device has its own processing speed. canvas animations are based on javascript's setInterval and setTimeout methods..which performs as per the device's processing speed..thats why canvas games are sometimes laggy on handhelds.

Comment: I'm not talking laggy, I'm talking frozen. The display remains unchanged until I click outside the canvas, otherwise everything is fine (The app keeps running, updating the pieces position and so on, but it's not displaying the updates until I click outside the canvas. Plus 800Mhz should be more than enough to update a minimal canvas at least once per second)

Comment: The answer is still the same..if its running in other devices smoothly

Comment: Other devices with different browsers. My tablet has almost the same processor and RAM, but I updated it from android 2.3.6 to 4.2, which takes even more resources (even notifications are laggy). So according to your argument it should be worse there but it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Check this link and see frames per seconds difference in different devices   http://briancribb.com/demo/bouncer/

Comment: between 29 and 40 fps.

Comment: but, surprise, it freezes during scroll (not before or after). So that's the problem, now I need to now how to fix it, i.e. disabling scrolling, at least inside the canvas. (And also zooming on double tap at least, if possible)

Comment: U can prevent scrolling with event.preventDefault();  and prevent zooming by user-scalable=no in meta tag

Comment: as stated on the question none of this options work.